# Everyone vs. Anyone

Tags: grammar, word-choice

> As **everyone** cuts it as well as he does, I always have my hair cut at Johnson's.

Or

> As **anyone** cuts it as well as he does, I always have my hair cut at Johnson's.

Which one is correct?

Comment: Neither one in my opinion. You should probably go with **no one.**

Comment: I agree that neither makes much sense as written. The first one could potentially be interpreted to mean that everyone *who works at Johnson's* cuts it as well as Johnson himself does so you always get haircuts there, but that interpretation is just an attempt to make sense out of something unclear.

Comment: In fact the second one could be read as meaning "any member of the general public cuts it as well as he does, not just hairdressers". If you take that interpretation that is a reason for avoiding Johnson's altogether!

Comment: “Correct”? That depends on context you haven’t provided. Both are grammatical, but the logic in each case sounds suspect.